# Spring and EJB integration

Tags: spring, ejb, integration

In my project we are using JSF and Spring WS (web tier), EJB 3.0 (service layer) and JPA (integration layer). We have exposed EJB in Spring container. 
All technologies are used with Spring. So, Spring is a used to bind all layers together. Hence, Spring is common for all layers of architecture.

I read that, many features provided by EJB is also available in Spring. Can't we replace EJB with Spring? Why, EJB and Spring both are used together.

I want to understand, what are benefits of using such architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is an alternative for EJB. Usually EJB and Spring are not used together unless it is a legacy application which is already developed based on EJB and Spring is wired later to support dependency injection and other framework benefits.

EJB is a heavy weight container which requires App containers like JBoss, WebSphere, or Weblogic.

Spring is a very light weight container which can be used in in web containers like Tomcat and even in Standalone applications. Also it provides support for many modules from front-end to back-end.

If there is a chance, you should consider replacing EJB with Spring bean in service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Does it means that Spring provides all features which are available from EJB 3.0. Clustering and all other features of EJB can also be acheived from Spring.